# How to make friction absolute 0 in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a educational game where you can change friction. I have tried using physics material and made friction 0 there and tried all different options for resultant friction but there is still some friction.(Using Unity 3D)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Reading through the [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html). They mention that 0 value "feels like ice". Which is really suckish if you are trying to do real-world physics education.

> Nvidia PhysX engine is tuned for performance and stability of
> simulation, and **does not necessarily present a close approximation of
> real-world physics**

This means you would have to find another way to keep the velocity of an object constant. Maybe explore Unity physics project settings, P.S I have tested this.

> **Edit > Project Settings >**
> [Change this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNohk.png)

Comment: Over time links break and images no longer load, so to help people in the future it would be great if you add a textual description of what the image shows as well.